# How to avoid big looking dialog title in jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI  1.8 and have the following code:

```
var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div')); 
$(newDiv).html('hello there');
$(newDiv).attr('title','Dialog Title');
$(newDiv).css('font-size','62.5%');
$(newDiv).dialog();
```

For some reason the Title looks really big, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/WwVgn/) for an example.

If there any way to make this look more like the version in the [jQuery demo](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use this css rule to apply smaller font size:

```
.ui-dialog{font-size: 62.5%;}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the style be applied to `.ui-dialog-titlebar` ? `.ui-dialog` will affect the font size of the entire dialog. Also no one has mentioned this yet, but you can also shrink down the title bar a bit with `.ui-dialog-titlebar { padding: 0 0.5em !important; }`

Comment: It's been almost a year since this answer, but at the time jQuery mobile seemed to rely heavily on the font size for its dimensions.  Thus, you could apply to the title only but that might cause a disproportionate look. You could also apply an important rule to the title bar, but again at the risk of disproportionate parts. More importantly, however, there may be styles not in use that you can't see. Rather than chasing them all down, personally, I'd prefer to set the font size. This all may be moot after a year of development, but if you only want the title bar changed, your code should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
.ui-dialog-title {
    font-size:14px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WwVgn/6/

Comment: It tells the browser to ignore any other CSS rules on that element

Comment: weird but there's a gray something underneath your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

The reason it looks good on the jQuery UI site is that they are using CSS style sheets to style the title bar. If you view their source, you'll see...

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I updated your JSFiddle with the example using this stylesheet: http://jsfiddle.net/WwVgn/5/

In any case, if you want to create your own style, head over to the [jQuery UI themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) website and you can easily customize and then export the stylesheets to use for yourself.

Comment: I updated my base jfiddle use their regular style and it still was fatty looking

Comment: @foreyez - Can you point me at the example that you updated? (Not finding it.) If you looked at my example, did it look okay to you?

Comment: your answer was wrong unfortunately, the reason it looked good is because of the "<body style="font-size:62.5%;">" i guess their default css is pretty dumb in that way... i had to update .ui-dialog to reduce font like the others mentioned. i guess their css dialog is just fat by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply using a different theme which has a large dialog title font. Try creating a new one with http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this bit of css:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```